# How to merge InfoPath forms?

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form

I have a set of forms having some information in repeating table... I need to merge these forms and view it in a single page... Is it possible?

Comment: This seems more like an infopath question rather than a SharePoint question? Can you clarify how you want to merge the forms?

Comment: It is like... If i have a repeating row in each form and if there are some 10 forms, I need all these 10 forms data in a single form

Comment: I've closed this question since it is not related to SharePoint. I would try asking your question on http://www.infopathdev.com/forums/

Answer (score 0):

Would having two InfoPath Form web parts on the page work in your case? Each would display one IP form.

Comment: I have more than 50 forms... I need to combine all of them...